# Drop down menu adds input fields with corresponding ID and label

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu, input

With Javascript, I created a drop down menu that generates the number of input fields that the user's selection (1-6) dictates.  But how do I make the newly generated input fields' IDs & labels correspond to their place-number in the list of input fields?  I hope that makes sense.  You'll see in my html I have [ brackets ] where I want the dynamically generated number to be.

**html:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="id_NOU">Number of Units:</label>
        <select name="NOU" id="id_NOA">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li class="list">
        <label>Unit []</label>
        <input type="text" id="unit[]"></input>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#id_NOU').change(function () {
        var total = $(this).val();

        //remove all
        $('.list').each(function (index) {
            if (index != 0) $(this).remove();
        });

        //create new ones
        for (var i = 2; i <= total; i++) {
            $('.list:first').clone().appendTo('ul');
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you so much for your help! I love JSFiddles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a better implementation would be to copy last field only and on further change keep the rest of the list intact

here is the code

```
var counter = 1;
$(function(){
    $("#id_NOA").on("change", function(){
        var $ul = $(this).parent().parent();
        var val = $(this).val();        
        while($ul.find(".list").length < val){
            var $item = $ul.find(".list:last").clone();
            $item.find("input").attr("id", "unit"+counter++);
            $item.find("label").html("Unit "+counter);
            $ul.append($item);
        }
        if($ul.find(".list").length >= val){
            $ul.find(".list:gt("+(val-1)+")").remove();
            counter = val;
        }

    });
});
```

here is a jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/EN687/1/

Comment: This does actually work better.  Copying from the final <li> is better.  There was a strange error in the other code that I couldn't figure out, as well, and this happens to fix that, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_NOU').change(function () {
        var total = $(this).val();

        //remove all
        $('.list').each(function (index) {
            if (index != 0) $(this).remove();
        });

        //create new ones
        for (var i = 2; i <= total; i++) {
            element = $('.list:first').clone();
            element.find('input').attr('id', 'unit' + i);
            element.find('label').html('Unit ' + i);
            element.appendTo('ul');
        }
    });
});
```

**Working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/6VQDR/1/